# Securing REST APIs with basic authentication

Tags: spring, spring-security, websecurity

I have multiple configs extending from `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`, and I would like to add a Basic Authentication for an endpoint. Basically I need match basic auth in the call with the user name password storaged in the DB (I am receiving a 403 forbidden.)

My endpoint is `/test` and my configuration:

```java
@Configuration
@Order(8)
@EnableGlobalAuthentication
public class WebSecurityConfigOauth extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AdminServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // Disable CSRF
        http
            .csrf().disable()    
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/test").hasAnyRole(RoleService.ROLE_ACCOUNT_ADMIN.toString())
                .and()
            .httpBasic()   
                .and()
            .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }

    @Override
    public AdminServiceImpl userDetailsService() {
        return userDetailsService;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(10);
    }
```

Also I added on UserDetailsServiceImpl :

```
@Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        String _username, _password;
        List<GrantedAuthority> _authorities;

        Admin admin = this.adminRepository.findByEmailAddress(username);
        if (admin != null) {
            _username = admin.getEmailAddress();
            _password = admin.getPassword();
            _authorities = new ArrayList<>();
            _authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ADMIN"));
        } else {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Admin not found with : " + username);
        }

        return new User(_username, _password, _authorities);
    }
```

Comment: If you are on Spring Security >= 5.4, you can add `logging.level.org.springframework.security=TRACE` to your `application.properties` and check the console logs to know why the 403 is happening

Comment: I  am on "5.3.5"

Comment: @ManuBouzas You can still change your log configuration and show your Spring Security DEBUG logs.

Comment: and debug user service, plz ..  suspect: password(encoding);!?

Comment: I am receiving a forbidden 403

Comment: http
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()

                .authorizeRequests()

                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, apiPrefix + "/t1").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, apiPrefix + "/t2").permitAll()
any idea how can I add an endpoint protected by basic auth?

Answer (score 0):

Please check your

```
.antMatchers("/tes")
```

since you said the endpoint is `/test`

Comment: sorry, it was an error , copy /paster.. still 403 forbidden

Comment: @ManuBouzas You should edit your question and fix the copy & paste error.

Comment: That's right, and as reviewers we can't edit it since what we would have to change is less than 6 characters long

Comment: Done, Thanks!, still no success , Basic Auth under 1 endpoint